# I hang when I try to ssh into a machine with my username (or su to my user)

Tags: linux, ssh

Yesterday I was freely able to ssh into server box-a, and it seemingly froze on me today so I killed my putty instance. I am now unable to ssh into it. It ssh's but the prompt does not appear. I am able to ssh using a different username, and then if i try to `su` into my user it hangs as well:

```
ssh notme@box-a
box-a:/home/notme> su myuser
Password:
```

and just hangs. Why could this be (on bash)?

Debug output:

```
ld-chhfemd01: ssh -vvv ld-chhfemd02
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug3: cipher ok: aes128-cbc [aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: 3des-cbc [aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: blowfish-cbc [aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: cast128-cbc [aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: arcfour [aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: aes192-cbc [aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: aes256-cbc [aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc]
debug3: ciphers ok: [aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc]
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ld-chhfemd02 [10.32.242.71] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: timeout: 30000 ms remain after connect
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arc\
four,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arc\
four,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 135/256
debug2: bits set: 514/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 79
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 79
debug1: Host 'ld-chhfemd02' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:79
debug2: bits set: 522/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/myuser/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa (0x2ac6af877020)
debug2: key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/myuser/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 149
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1 fp f1:2c:f7:09:b6:b7:ff:83:c5:e7:98:da:f4:fe:ea:66:05:32:f7:9c
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list unix:18.0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 0
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: ospeed 38400
debug3: tty_make_modes: ispeed 38400
debug3: tty_make_modes: 1 3
debug3: tty_make_modes: 2 28
debug3: tty_make_modes: 3 127
debug3: tty_make_modes: 4 21
debug3: tty_make_modes: 5 4
debug3: tty_make_modes: 6 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 7 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 8 17
debug3: tty_make_modes: 9 19
debug3: tty_make_modes: 10 26
debug3: tty_make_modes: 12 18
debug3: tty_make_modes: 13 23
debug3: tty_make_modes: 14 22
debug3: tty_make_modes: 18 15
debug3: tty_make_modes: 30 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 31 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 32 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 33 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 34 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 35 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 36 1
debug3: tty_make_modes: 37 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 38 1
debug3: tty_make_modes: 39 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 40 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 41 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 50 1
debug3: tty_make_modes: 51 1

debug3: tty_make_modes: 52 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 53 1
debug3: tty_make_modes: 54 1
debug3: tty_make_modes: 55 1
debug3: tty_make_modes: 56 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 57 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 58 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 59 1
debug3: tty_make_modes: 60 1
debug3: tty_make_modes: 61 1
debug3: tty_make_modes: 62 0
debug3: tty_make_modes: 70 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env GREP_COLOR
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
Last login: Wed Jan 30 14:38:32 2013 from ld-chhfemd01.rocks.com
Kickstart-Installed Fri Oct 12 17:17:04 CDT 2012
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)
```

so it seems to log in but then hang.

Comment: One way to get this situation is if your user name is authenticated using an off-machine lookup, like NIS or LDAP, while your second user name is local.

Comment: try the command with debugging enabled, so we can see where the hang is occurring. "ssh -vvv noteme@box-a"

Comment: I added the output to the edit..it's very long

Comment: To clarify my previous comment - if the remote authentication server is down or not responding, your machine will hang trying to complete the login step. Your ssh output seems to indicate that you made it through ssh, but not local login.

Comment: True, it suddenly worked again. This is strange. Happened to another friend of mine but not all usernames were affected.

Comment: Can you log in as another user, kill any ssh process that is attached to the first session, and restart sshd? Something got that connection wedged _real_ good. Would be interesting to find out why/how...

Answer (score 1):

Possible culprits:

1. `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.inputrc` - please make the content of these available
2. PS1
3. PAM authentication